# Mensaje de "Commands completed successfully." SQL server

Tags: php, sqlsrv

Buenas tardes compañeros, el dia de hoy me dedique a hacer una carga masiva desde un archivo de excel pero me di cuenta que al momento de ejecutar una Query en php me retornaba error a pesar de que si efectuaba los cambios y decidi ver que es lo que arrojaba cada Qeury por si sola en SQL server, para lo que me arroja el siguiente mensaje "Commands completed successfully."

Esto solo me pasa en una sola base de datos, ya que tengo mas instanciadas en el mismo servidor, y no se que este pasando, como deba configurarla, la he montado y desmontado en varias ocaciones pero sigue mostrando este mensaje en vez de mostrar "(1) rows affected" como siempre, esto deriva a que cuando en php espera la respuesta de la base de datos, no reconozca si es true o false

Alguien me podria apoyar como hacer que muestr el mensaje correcto o como debo configurar cuando me mande este tipo de respuestas

mi php es el siguiente:

```
<?php
  public function Proceso_cambio_de_estado_rdfda_carga_masvia($id_det,$estatus_cred){
        include_once 'conexion.php';
        include_once 'sesion.php';
        $conexion = new ConexionSQL();
        $con = $conexion->ObtenerConexionBD();
        $query = "INSERT INTO Etapa_poc (
        [id_proc_det]
      ,[user_alta]
      ,[fecha_alta]
      ,estatus
      ,[id_determinante]
      ,[estatus_det_cam]
        ) 
        VALUES(21,'BOVEDASA',GETDATE(),'A',$id_det,'$estatus_cred')";
      
        $prepare = sqlsrv_query($con, $query);
        if ($prepare) {
            return true;
            $conexion->CerrarConexion($con);
          
        } else {
           
            $errorsql = print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), false);
           
            return $errorsql;
            $conexion->CerrarConexion($con);
        }

    }
?>
```

y en SQL server ejecutando esta Query me arroja esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien conoce algo o sabe de algo me pudiera apoyar a solucionar esto se lo agradeceria muchisimo!

Comment: *`Commands completed successfully`* significa que los comandos se ejecutaron con éxito, o lo que es lo mismo, no ha habido ningún problema, entonces, ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: Pasa que con un insert into debe aparecer `1 rows affected` indicando que se agregó una columna además del mensaje de éxito.

Comment: No. Considera que estás en un entorno PHP y el SGBD desde PHP no emitirá mensajes por defecto. Si quieres que muestre `1 rows affected` debes programarlo explícitamente, cosa que no veo estés haciendo en tu código PHP, actualmente estás retornando `true` sin más.

Comment: Puede que tengas razon pero eso no explica que en otras DB si se aprecie el mensaje que necesito que mande con esta misma forma de codigo de php, por eso creo que deberia ser un problema de configuracion y no de programación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás en el entorno de PHP, y para interactuar con la base de datos estás usando el controlador [SQLSRV](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.sqlsrv.php), el cual tiene sus propias funciones para consultar a la base de datos, para saber el número de filas afectadas, etc.

Si observas, en tu código estás devolviendo `true` en el caso de éxito, eso es lo que obtendrás, si quieres otra cosa, deberás gestionarlo usando las funciones propias del controlador.

Por otra parte, tu código no es seguro, para este caso, en vez de usar `sqlsrv_query` debes usar [`sqlsrv_prepare()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php). No basta con llamar a tu variable `$prepare`, no, debes escribir una consulta preparada real y pasar los parámetros como se explica en la documentación.

Aplicando lo dicho, tu código podría quedar así:

```
<?php
  public function Proceso_cambio_de_estado_rdfda_carga_masvia($id_det,$estatus_cred){
        include_once 'conexion.php';
        include_once 'sesion.php';
        $conexion = new ConexionSQL();
        $con = $conexion->ObtenerConexionBD();
        
        if($con) { 
            $query = "INSERT INTO Etapa_poc (
            [id_proc_det]
            ,[user_alta]
            ,[fecha_alta]
            ,estatus
            ,[id_determinante]
            ,[estatus_det_cam]
            ) 
            VALUES(?,?,GETDATE(),?,?,?)";
    
            $id=21;
            $user='BOVEDASA';
            $estatus='A';
            $params = array(&$id, &$user, &$estatus, &$id_det, &$estatus_cred);  
            $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($con, $query, $params);
            if ($stmt && sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
                $rows=sqlsrv_rows_affected($stmt);
                if(!$rows) {
                    $data=array( "success"=>false, "msg"=>sprintf("Error: %s", sqlsrv_errors()[0]['message']) );
                } elseif( $rows == -1) {
                    $data=array( 
                                    "success"=>false, 
                                    "msg"=>"Error no indentificado" 
                                );
                } else {
                    $data=array( 
                                    "success"=>true, 
                                    "msg"=>sprintf("%d rows affected", $rows) 
                                );
                }
            } else {           
                $data = array('success'=>false, 'msg'=>sqlsrv_errors()[0]['message']);
            }
            $conexion->CerrarConexion($con);
        } else { 
            $data = array('success'=>false, 'msg'=>'No hay conexión');  
        }
        return $data;
    }
?>
```

El código, como podrás ver, es un poco más largo. Pero es un código en el cual se prevén todos los posibles errores. Como criterio, he creado un array llamado `$data` en el cual habrá una clave llamada `success` que será `true` únicamente cuando haya habido filas afectadas, en todos los otros casos será `false` y siempre tendrá una clave `msg` con un mensaje descriptivo de lo que haya ocurrido, o errores obtenidos con `sqlsrv_errors`. Esto último no es recomendable en producción, porque podrían ser revelados datos sensibles de la base de datos.

Finalmente, el código ahora es seguro, porque se usa una consulta preparada real. Observa que algunos datos, aunque estaban escritos a mano en la consulta, los he pasado a variables, porque supongo que en un futuro esos datos podrían ser variables.

Espero te sea de utilidad, y cualquier duda pregunta en comentarios debajo de la respuesta.

Comment: voy a probar esta forma y te informo si soluciono mi problema, por que como tal, siempre habia usado este codigo y habia funcionado, pero pues tambien cabe recalcar que no se bien que es lo que este pasando asi que no me cierro a ninguna alternativa